# Is it possible to share the revenue between two accounts?

Tags: google-adsense

I have one website which is ran by me and my friend, but I want to share the revenue from the ads without having to send him money every month, is there an option to share the revenue between two accounts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a script that shows ads on a rotation. For example, it would show your ads 50% of the time and his ads the other 50% of the time. Your earnings would not be identical, though... because one of you may get more clicks, your clicks may be worth different amount depending on just, really timing and the keyword the visitor came in on.

That said, it's the most common way people solve your problem. If you would like more information, just look up stuff regarded ads on rotation. This is the model HubPages uses to allow its users to make money: ~40% of the time the ads shown are from HubPages' AdSense account and the other 60% of the time the ads are shown, it's ads from the writer's account.

Comment: I thought about that, I really wanted an equal share, but if there's no other solution, I think I will use this one.

Comment: Yeah, you may end making more or he may end up making more. It's really the luck of the draw but it probably the easiest way to do it. Plus, then you wouldn't have to worry about having to put ALL the income from the site on your taxes and then making deductions on what was his part -- you would just have to claim what's being brought into your own AdSense account.